# Can I make a product which infringes on a patent for my own use..?

Tags: application

In reference to the patent:email id id [US1588898](https://www.google.com/patents/US1588898)

i need to have detailed information about this patent as i wanted to make a project on aerators.

Comment: This patent expired, you can use invention.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents! Unfortunately, this question is too broad for us to be able to answer. We're better with questions specific to aspects of the patent system, as compared to anything about their underlying technologies. I've marked this as a duplicate of a question that should help you, although it isn't an exact duplicate. If you want to [edit] your post to make it on-topic, we'll see if we can get it reopened.